# Covert the JAVA function to PHP

Tags: php, password-encryption

Below is the java function. I want to this function on php.

```
public static String getPassword(String spId, String password, String timestamp) 
{
    try {
        String dgStr = spId + password + timestamp;

        byte[] enc = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256").digest(dgStr.getBytes());
        return new String(Base64.encodeBase64(new String(Hex.encodeHex(enc)).toUpperCase().getBytes()));
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}
```

Already i have used a code see below,

base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha256", $spPassword, true));

Is it valid? If not then please suggest me.

Comment: This is a java script function. I want to same function in PHP for password encryption.

Answer (score 1):

The exact conversion of your Java function is:

```
function makeHash($spID,$password)
{
    $timestamp = time();
    return hash('sha256',$spID.$password.$timestamp);
}
```

Use it like:

```
echo makeHash(12,'password123');
```

Comment: Can you tell me php of following algorithm to encrypt the password?
1 Create a block of data to be encrypted
2 Write the unencrypted password value
3 Encrypt the block of data created in step 2 with the public portion of the password key certificate. Use RSA algorithm with PKCS#1.5 (not OAEP) and add the result to the encrypted stream, this becomes the encrypted password to be submitted via the broker {In Java, the scheme is short-coded as "RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding". Alternatively you may use "RSA/NONE/PKCS1Padding"}
4 Convert resulting encrypted byte array into a string using base64 encoding

Comment: Please go through http://php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.ciphers.php

Comment: I m trying this to get ciphertext - $key = pack('H*', $keyValue); 
$key = pack('H*', $keyValue);    
$key_size =  strlen($key);
$plaintext = 'Pass my password for encryption'

$iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
# creates a cipher text compatible with AES (Rijndael block size = 128)
$ciphertext = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $plaintext, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
$ciphertext = $iv . $ciphertext;
$ciphertext_base64 = base64_encode($ciphertext);